# Nginx - Prevent Access to Debug file

Tags: debug, nginx

I am logging to debug file

```
wp-content/debug.log
```

but any user can download the file, if they put the url on their browser. How could I prevent access to this file using Nginx?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've frequently seen this used in Apache 2.2:

```
<Files "debug.log">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

but that's [deprecated](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) in Apache 2.4:

> The `Allow`, `Deny`, and `Order` directives, provided by `mod_access_compat`,
>   are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid
>   using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

I just tested with the [Require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) directive in Apache 2.4:

> Require all denied 
>   *Access is denied unconditionally.*

with:

```
<Files "debug.log">
   Require all denied
</Files>
```

and it seems to block it with *403 forbidden*.

Note that it will block access from `example.tld/debug.log`,  `example.tld/wp-content/debug.log` etc.

**Update**

I just noticed that you mentioned NginX, so I tested various location patterns and this seems to work:

```
location ~* /debug\.log$
{
    deny  all;
}
```

where the `~*` modifier is for case insensitive regular expression matching.