# Using debug log in production, is that a security concern?

Tags: debug, wp-debug

Is having the `WP_DEBUG_LOG` enabled, and having a `debug.log` in a production environment a security issue?

Comment: Which debug log are you talking about, are you looking for "yes" or "no" for this?

Comment: The WP_DEBUG in the debug.log file

Answer (score 2):

I would consider it a security concern if everyone is able to view the `debug.log` file from the browser.

It could reveal e.g. paths, plugins and their problems.

There are though ways to restrict access to it via Nginx or Apache.

Another problem I've seen with logging to `debug.log` on production sites is that it's not auto log-rotated, so it can grow fast for busy problematic sites. It's easy to forget about it there, until the disk is full or the huge size starts to slow things down.

ps: I just remembered I wrote something about access restrictions [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/247632/26350).